# how to get data from json in servlet

Tags: json, ajax, servlets

```
function getvalue1(){
    debugger
    var str=document.getElementById("SystemName").value;
    var str1=document.getElementById("IP").value;
    var str2=document.getElementById("SystemLevel").value;
    var str3=document.getElementById("Ownera").value;
    var str4=document.getElementById("Ownerb").value;
    var str5=document.getElementById("SystemDesc").value;
    var str6=document.getElementById("SystemDate").value;
    var str7=document.getElementById("Recorder").value;

    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
        url:"../AddServlet",
        data: {    
            str:str,
            str1:str1,
            str2:str2,
            str3:str3,
            str4:str4,
            str5:str5,
            str6:str6,
            str7:str7
        },
        async:false,
        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success:function (data) {
            $.message.alert('successful');
        },
        error:function () {
            alert("failedjump");
        }
    });
}
```

The previous is my js code, I wanna to take these "strs" into the servlet, I programmed servlet part to get the data is
            [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1PWJ.png)
But these strings are null in the servlet. How can I get the JSON data? thx!

Comment: "enter image description here" — Why are you posting fuzzy pictures of code? Code is text. Text can be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

`getParameter` will read standard form encoded data, not JSON data.

This wouldn't normally be a problem because you are sending standard form encoded data, not JSON.

However, since you have said `contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8"`, you are **claiming** to be sending JSON, so it isn't being parsed.

Remove that line.